# Is the Slide-to-Android SlidingTab source or widget available for use?

Tags: android, android-widget, slider

I'm looking to implement a SlidingTab ie: lock slider or slide-to-answer type thing in my app. I figured it'd a common thing so the source or widget would be available for use but I can't find it anywhere.

Would I have to build a custom one myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same look and feel of the `SlidingTab`, yes, you have to implement a custom one yourself! Look [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch#vvzdNcpFo6U/trunk/CSipSimple/src/com/csipsimple/widgets/SlidingTab.java) for the source code and [here](http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CSipSimple/res/drawable-hdpi/) for image resources.

If you need something similar you can use [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) or customize a [`SeekBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html). 
Let me know what you choose! ;)